# Segmentation fault when returning a nullptr in my strpbrk function

Tags: c++, c-strings

I need help returning a nullptr in my strpbrk implementation. Is there a way to return a nullptr without triggering a Segmentation fault?
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
const char *STRPBRK(const char *haystack, const char *char_list) {
// TODO
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < haystack[i] != '\0';i++){
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < char_list[j] != '\0';j++){
        if(haystack[i] == char_list[j]){
            return &haystack[i];
        }
    }
}
return nullptr;
}

int main() {
char data[] = "HelloWorld";
std::cout<<"output: "<<STRPBRK(data,"ello"); //output: elloWorld
std::cout<<"output: "<<STRPBRK(data,"pp"); //output: STRPBRK
}
```

Output should look like this when returning a nullptr when no such char is found

output: STRPBRK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return value in caller and avoid passing `nullptr` to `std::cout`.

```
#include <iostream>
const char *STRPBRK(const char *haystack, const char *char_list) {
// TODO
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < haystack[i] != '\0';i++){
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < char_list[j] != '\0';j++){
        if(haystack[i] == char_list[j]){
            return &haystack[i];
        }
    }
}
return nullptr;
}

void work(const char* data, const char* query) {
    const char* res = STRPBRK(data,query);
    std::cout << "output: " << (res != nullptr ? res : "STRPBRK");
}

int main() {
char data[] = "HelloWorld";
work(data,"ello"); //output: elloWorld
work(data,"pp"); //output: STRPBRK
}
```